# Changing Loop to include a $var

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the code below it has a `foreach` what would be the best way to alter it so it allows me to check `$instock`.  I have tried using the `if` statement within the `foreach` but then it doesn't see the `endforeach`

**Loop:**

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product','meta_key' => '_featured','meta_value' => 'yes','orderby' =>'rand','order' => 'DESC');

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
    $price = $product->price;
    $instock = $product->is_in_stock();
?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail Product_Box">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?php the_title()?><br />
                    <span class="text-color">$<?php echo $price; ?></span>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean solution would be to skip the product if it's not in stock. Thus what you would get is the following.

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product','meta_key' => '_featured','meta_value' => 'yes','orderby' =>'rand','order' => 'DESC');

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
    $price = $product->price;
    $instock = $product->is_in_stock();

    if (!$instock) {
        continue;
    }
?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail Product_Box">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><?php the_title()?><br />
                    <span class="text-color">$<?php echo $price; ?></span>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have just tired this and it just does not display anything

Comment: Could you tell me what $instock contains for a product that is not in stock?

Comment: Ok I have had a break through still not 100% working - Thanks for getting me on the right direction!

I have discovered that there is a `$product->stock_status;` that I am now using for $instock this gives me a result of `instock` and `outofstock` but im still getting an empty loop if I use an IF

Comment: Check the settings for each product. Could be that it's using a field that has no value in it and thus returning a false out of stock.

Comment: I have tried I cant seem to get it showing in a full array of data however if I try !$stock == 'outofstock' it only shows 2x in stock products

Comment: It could well be because of the arguments you pass to the get_posts function. Try it without a posts per page and frankly any other argument apart from **'post_type' => 'product'**. If you get the desired products shown (anything expect the out of stock ones) there's something wrong with those arguments. :-)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Did you figure out the cause of your problem?